# Question about the boundedness of an integral operator.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $E= \{f \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]:f(1)=0 \}$ with the supremum norm. Consider the functional $\varphi$ on $E$ defined by $\varphi(f)=\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx$ for $f \in E$. Show that $\varphi$ is bounded with norm $\|\varphi\|=1$. Then show that for every $0 \neq f \in E$ one has $|\varphi |<\|f\|_{\infty}$.

$Proof:$ We observe that
\begin{align*}|\varphi (f)|
&=\Big|\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx \Big| \\
&\leq \int^{1}_{0}|f(x)|dx \\
&\leq \int^{1}_{0}\|f\|_{\infty}dx.
\end{align*}

Therefore $|\varphi (f)| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ for every $f \in E$, with the inequality if and only if $f \neq 0$, since $f(0)=1$ for all $f \in E$. So $\varphi$ is bounded and $\|\varphi\| \leq 1$. To show that $\|\varphi\| = 1$, we consider, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the functions
$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if }t \in \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right] \\
      -nt+n & \text{if }t \in \left[1-\frac{1}{n},1\right]. \\
\end{cases}$$
Clearly $\|f_n\|_\infty =1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\sup \varphi(f_n)=1$. Therefore, $\|\varphi\|=1.$

Could you please provide feedback regarding the reasoning in the proof above, especially the use of the functions $f_n$. Any feedback is really appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant $f_n(x)=-nt+n$, not $-nt+t$ for $t \geq 1-\frac 1 n$. Except for this typo are argument is fine.